# How to lock an email in outlook during async process

Tags: c#, asynchronous, outlook

I have a C# application where the user can copy an email from Outlook (msg file) into a network storage. The application operates async to free the user to continue working. The problem is, that if the user moves or deletes the email before the application has finished, an exception is thrown that the object no longer exists.

How can I prevent Outlook from 'messing with my mail object' until my application is done working with it?

I have tried

```
lock(object)
{
//Do stuff
}
```

But that only seems to apply if I have several async processes running, it's not preventing actions by the user (or maybe I am doing something wrong?).
I thought about handling it by using events, but seems like the correct solution is to 'lock the object', rather than trying to find ways to catch possible actions that might affect the object.

Edit: Here is the code for further info.

```
foreach (Outlook.MailItem mailItem in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection)
{
        lock (mailItem)
        {
               // Async process
        }
}
```

Comment: are you using the office interop?

Comment: Yes, I am using interop. I tried set the object in lock(object) to both 'this' and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem. Neither seemed to work.

Comment: Can you not call `Copy` on the item and then work from the copy?

Comment: Thanks - It might be a good (simple) idea. Once the the application is done handling the email, it assigns an 'Archive' category (tag) to the email in Outlook. That way, the user can quickly get an overview of e.g. the inbox, and see which emails has not been archived. 

But I guess I can search for the email (in case it was moved from e.g. 'inbox' to 'deleted') based on the attributes from my copied mail-item and then apply the category to the mail (where-ever it may be).

Comment: No luck - Tested the suggestion with copy. That creates a copy in the outlook folder, thus duplicating the email.

Comment: OK - Seems like this is not possible. I have now implemented Plan-B, which is to control this using the Move-event, which will catch delete as well. But thanks for suggestions.